# How to stream music tracks using Spotify Web PlayBack SDK using Express, React, NodeJS

Tags: reactjs, node.js, express, spotify

I am unable to make the music play on the music/spotify player that I have created on my MERN application. I have tried to follow all the steps mentioned in the Spotify developer portal. It still is not working. I want to implement a music player through my code in which when the user clicks the play button on a particular track, it must launch the spotify music player and the particular track must play. The control buttons in the music player must in turn be able to control the music track. However, nothing seems to be happening. When I click on the play button with circle on hovering over a particular track, none of the troubleshooting messages are appearing on the console. log. However when I click on the play button under the controls, I get an error: "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')". Not sure what I am missing and where it is going wrong. Can anyone help if i share the code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.